# Navigate to parent folder with Backspace key in open file dialog

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, dialog

I have two laptops with Ubuntu 18.04: a MacBook Pro and a Xiaomi Mi Air.

In the Xiaomi I can navigate to parent folder with Backspace key in Open File dialogs.

In Macbook I can't and I have to use CMD+Up combination.

How can I change the keyboard shortcuts for the Open File dialog?

With nautilus and nemo there's not problem. It's only with dialogs.

Comment: What do you mean with "system"? I'm talking of GTK2 Open File dialogs. Dialogs that appear in almost every application when CTRL+o is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution (for GTK 3):

Create a file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
@binding-set MyOwnFilechooserBindings
{
    bind "BackSpace" { "up-folder" () };
}

filechooser
{
    -gtk-key-bindings: MyOwnFilechooserBindings
}
```

Comment: Strange the Backspace worked for you on one of your computers. For me, on a Dell XPS 13 3950, Backspace also does not work in a GTK3 file dialog. In a GTK2 dialog, Backspace works, but Alt+down/up work differently - these navigate you through your history.

Comment: Any other way other than changing .config file?